# Upload file to Spark Java

Tags: java, web, spark-java

I am trying to create a folder which contains uploaded files. I have seen some examples that saving files into the absolute folder such as **D:/tmp** or Home directory. My question is I am trying to put my uploaded files into a folder which is inside the project folder.
[image: Upload folder should contains uploaded files]

I also tried to get project folder using like this :

```
    public static String getProjectFolder(){
         return System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/";
    }
```

Result become something like this, and file not found exception inside the Html file!

http://localhost:1234/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/java/PROJECT_NAME/upload/genres/action.jpg

What is the best way to add folder into my project? Or should I use hardcoded folder for it ?

Comment: Please learn to use configuration files instead of hardcoding stuff. Java provides the Properties class. You can use that to load an `.ini` structured file. It even allows comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the folder that you want to upload files to as the *static files folder* using `staticFiles.externalLocation()`.

The only folder the client can reach, either for getting content from OR uploading to, is the folder you set using the static files location API `staticFiles.externalLocation()`. You can see also an example for that [here](https://github.com/tipsy/spark-file-upload/blob/master/src/main/java/UploadExample.java).

When I run my server locally, I define it to be:

```
staticFiles.externalLocation(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources");
```

This is regarding what your question.

---

You might run into an issue though. Because now you probably have two locations that you want public:

- The resources folder (with all the JavaScripts, CSSs, etc. Typically `/src/main/resources`)
- Upload folder (to let the user upload files)

Having both of these the same location is not a good practice. I managed to resolve that by creating a symbolic link called `files` inside the public folder.

```
abcmbp:resources abc$ pwd
/Users/abc/dev/wspace/proj1/src/main/resources

abcmbp:resources abc$ ls -l files
lrwxr-xr-x  1 abc  staff  27 Mar  3 21:20 files -> /Users/abc/appUploadFolder/
```

Then, in the post handle of the uploading path, I give this folder as the destination, and this way I have a separation between resources and uploaded files.

Comment: I have not wrote uploading implementation, but I do not want to mix resources and uploading file like you said. Can i implement 2 static folder and save uploaded folder? Or there might be an only folder which clients can reach

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu That's exactly the thing - you cannot have two static folders, only one (it makes sense - if you could have two how could the server decide which one to target for a request). This is why I used the symbolic link.